# What is the difference between UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window and UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwindow, uiapplication

Can anyone help me understand the difference between the following two lines:

```
[UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window addSubview:myView];
```

```
[UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow addSubview:myView];
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They could be the same on iOS. When they are different, usually you are presenting another window other than the app delegate's main window. Your app can have many windows but only the `keyWindow` is the window that is visible on the screen and receiving events (example could be a UIAlert when visible and receiving events it is the keywindow) reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/WindowScreenRolesinApp/WindowScreenRolesinApp.html

from the documentation:

- For `UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window`:

> The window to use when presenting a storyboard. This property contains
>   the window used to present the app’s visual content on the device’s
>   main screen.

i.e this is the property `window` that you have in your `AppDelegate.h` file.

- For `UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow`:

> This property holds the UIWindow object in the windows array that is
>   most recently sent the makeKeyAndVisible message.

On iOS you call `makeKeyAndVisible` in your `AppDelegate.m` inside

`application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

You made the created appDelegate window the keyWindow. Usually, bank apps switch the key window when the app is put in the background to protect the users sensitive information when the home button is doubled tapped and switch back to the main delegate window when the app is in foreground.

**This answer is in collaboration with: @SipkeSchoorstra, @D-Mx and @andyDarwin**

Comment: Downvoted because this is not correct, see Jeffrey Thomas' and Andy Darwin's answers.

Comment: @SipkeSchoorstra thanks for your feedback the answer is updated.

Comment: This is wrong. Not only the keyWindow is visible, for example alerts use separate windows to be displayed. A window is considered the key window when it is currently receiving keyboard and non touch-related events. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/WindowScreenRolesinApp/WindowScreenRolesinApp.html

Comment: Hey @D-Mx, yeah looks like I forgot to mention that the key window is visible and receiving events, updated just now to include that. I would say the answer is not wrong but incomplete, thank you for helping making stackoverflow friendly and collaborative place :)

Answer (score 42):

For most uses, they will be the same… but not always.

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow` is the window which is currently being displayed on the device. This is normally your application's window, but could be a system window.

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window` is the window your application is expected to use.

Which one should be used? Well that all depends on context.

If you are updating part of your application, then you should add views to your application's window. This is almost always what you want to do.

Personally, I always use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window addSubview:view]` or `[self.view.window addSubView:view]` (within `UIViewController`) when I need to add a view directly to the window.

There might be some times when you want to present a view to the window currently being displayed, regardless if the window belongs to your application or is some system window. I've not run into that situation.

Comment: Since you don't know which screen was last present ...would it be good to use `keyWindow` for showing an alert when you receive remote notification? I'm talking about iOS versions older than iOS10 where you didn't have the [`willPresent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter)?

Answer (score 7):

Basheer_CAD's answer is not right. They are not always the same in iOS.

Jeffery Thomas's answer is right and let me provide a concrete example.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"keyWindow --------> %@",[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController);
    NSLog(@"delegate.window --> %@",[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController);
    NSLog(@"self.view.window -> %@",self.view.window.rootViewController);
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"keyWindow --------> %@",[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController);
    NSLog(@"delegate.window --> %@",[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController);
    NSLog(@"self.view.window -> %@",self.view.window.rootViewController);
}
```

The output is:

```
keyWindow --------> (null)
delegate.window --> <ViewController: 0x10030c0e0>
self.view.window -> (null)
keyWindow --------> <UIApplicationRotationFollowingController: 0x100204510>
delegate.window --> <ViewController: 0x10030c0e0>
self.view.window -> <ViewController: 0x10030c0e0>
```

When `viewDidLoad`, actually the window is not ready yet, so there is nothing for the system window. `UIAlertView` may dominate the window, so you cannot get the window you want.

Comment: thanks for for your feedback, please check my updated answer. Your answer is upvoted therefore :)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest setup is to just have one `UIWindow`. Usually that window is kept as a property on your app delegate. The `keyWindow` is the one that is designated to receive keyboard and other non-touch related events. Only one window at a time may be the key window. So if you add a 2nd window and make it the `keyWindow` (via `[window makeKeyAndVisible]`), your lines return different windows!