# Presenting iOS 8 UIAlertController from Singleton Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I currently have a locationManager (not CLLocationManager) singleton that is getting my location when the app starts and that manages the rest of the location services in the app.

When getting initialized the location manager if the state is denied triggers an alert prompting to change the authorization state. Since it is a nsobject I can't present it, and I've been looking for other options but most are hacks. Is it actually possible to present it this way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure some will argue about whether or not you SHOULD. With that being said, you COULD by doing this:

```
[[(<#YourAppDelegate#> *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window].rootViewController presentViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#> completion:<#^(void)completion#>];
```

It should be noted that if you're using a Mac app as opposed to iOS, multiple windows could be present and you may want to use the key window.  This could occasionally be a system window so it's something you should be aware of.  Here's a post explaining the differences:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21698751/2611971

If you'd prefer to present on your keyWindow, you could use this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#> completion:<#^(void)completion#>];
```

Comment: `window` may be `nil` in some cases. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21698751/1445366

Comment: @AaronBrager - That seems to pertain more to Mac Apps, however I think it's relevant, so I did add an addendum linking to that thread as well as a demonstration showing the `keyWindow` approach.  Anything else you think should be there?

Comment: I'm going to try your method Logan and write back. What are the scenarios that code has given you problems?

Comment: How do you set key window property?

Comment: If you're using storyboards, I'm pretty sure it's set automatically. Otherwise on your window call 'makeKeyAndVisible'

Comment: Ok, it worked but it doesn't appear if I have any modal view controller present

Comment: If your app doesn't use storyboards, and you never set the `window` property, it'll be `nil`, even in iOS apps.

Comment: @AaronBrager - I see what you were saying now.  I haven't used storyboards in a while.  Will `keyWindow` be nil in that situation?  Jake, you're saying that if you've presented a VC modally then this doesn't present on top of it?  You could check the `.presentedViewController` on your rootVC and if that exists, present on that vc instead.

Comment: As long as you've called `makeKeyAndVisible` on a window (or used a storyboard), `keyWindow` will not be `nil`.

Comment: However, some views are presented in separate windows, like UIAlertView, UIActionSheet, and SVProgressHUD. So `keyWindow` might not be the window you want either.

Comment: It may work Logan, gonna try it. Although of what can I see it could get problems if there are several modals presented by modals

Answer (score 1):

You can set your main view controller object as an observer for a `AuthorizationDenied` notification via `Notification Center`. And post that notification when it's denied, and your view controller will get notified.

In your `View Controller` loading:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(authorizationDenied:) name:@"AuthorizationDenied" object:nil];
```

In your singleton class:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AuthorizationDenied" object:nil];
```