# The right way to set a viewController as a root viewController

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

In the scenario where you have a viewController which you want to present as root view above everything else what is the right way to do this?

```
let Storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let MY_VIEW = Storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VIEWID")


//Is this the right way?
UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(MY_VIEW, animated: true, completion: nil)


//Or this?     
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(MY_VIEW, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In other words why would you use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.window?` over `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?` and in what scenarios? What would be the pros/cons of using one or the other?

Comment: read differences : [diffrences in keyWindow & Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698482/diffrence-between-uiapplication-sharedapplication-delegate-window-and-u)

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follow.

```
 let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VIEWID") as! SplashVC

        if self.window != nil {
            self.window!.rootViewController = rootController
        }
```

**advantage of this is not getting crash when window is nil.**

Another way is that(Most secure way i think)

```
   let navigationController:UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
   let rootViewController:UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VIEWID") as! LoginVC
   navigationController.viewControllers = [rootViewController]
   self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let viewController: MainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as! MainViewController

            let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
            rootViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```