# When to use UIApplication.keywindow and UIApplicationDelegate.window?

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

I'm working on a somewhat new project (with Swift) and I just realized `UIApplication.keywindow` and `UIApplicationDelegate.window` are being used (apparently) like they are the same.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698482/diffrence-between-uiapplication-sharedapplication-delegate-window-and-u) I understand the are in fact NOT the same; but it's really not clear to me why or how they are different, when should each one be used.

Also the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/keyWindow) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UIApplicationDelegate/window) is rather cryptic in the meaning of each attribute, so I don't really understand if I can use one or the other, if I should one of both. In any case, any light on this mess would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: What are you using the window for? The window object is used infrequently on iOS compared to OSX.

Comment: Care to explain further what you mean? I use the window to get the root and push a controller. Don't really understand which one should I use, or if I can use either one of them, and why.

Comment: Most of our projects have a UINavigationController, so we push controllers via `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`. We normally put the root viewController into the app delegate, so there's no need to use the `window` property. Having said that, there are times we use it to present alert-type views.

Comment: In any case, I would use `UIApplicationDelegate.window` for what you're doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [diffrence between \[\[\[\[UIApplication sharedApplication\] delegate\] window\] and \[\[UIApplication sharedApplication\].keyWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698482/diffrence-between-uiapplication-sharedapplication-delegate-window-and-u)