# _UIInteractiveHighlightEffectWindow's isHidden property default is YES?

Tags: ios

I got a window from the code below in iOS11:
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject;

its infomations were printed on console is like this:
<_UIInteractiveHighlightEffectWindow: 0x7fdfe84b88e0; frame = (0 0; 375 812); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; gestureRecognizers = ; layer = >

what's confused me is its isHidden property default value is YES, why ? I tried to search some more infomation about it with key word "_UIInteractiveHighlightEffectWindow", l got nothing but it's a new property in iOS11. Apple also gives nothing about it .
Any one know something about it ? Any help is appreciated ! thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "_UIInteractiveHighlightEffectWindow" is new on iOS, and there isn't much information about it currently.
However, if the topmost layers is need, use [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow instead of [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject, that would probably solve the problem.
I found some good explanation here:

[diffrence between [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] and [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698482/diffrence-between-uiapplication-sharedapplication-delegate-window-and-u)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! l have changed [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject to [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow .It works ! But what's _UIInteractiveHighlightEffectWindow used for ? l'm really curious about it ! But apple offers no information about it ! This really confuses me !