# requestReview() deprecated in iOS 14, Alternative for xamarin.forms?

Tags: swift, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios14

I'm using

```
SKStoreReviewController.RequestReview ();
```

in a dependency service for Xamarin.Forms. However this is now deprecated from iOS 14. And I want to know how to integrate with the new
`UIWindowScene`

```
requestReview(in windowScene: UIWindowScene)
```

in Xamarin.Forms

Comment: I'm using [James Montemagno's StoreReviewPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/StoreReviewPlugin) and it's been working just fine on iOS 14 and above.

Comment: @MichalDiviš it might not work after a while and I don't want my project dependent on an update from that nuget. I'm screwed if they don't give an update in time.

Comment: Fair enough, I hope you find the answer soon. Best of luck!

Comment: However, you can take a look at the plug-in on GitHub and steal the iOS code you need.

Comment: They are also using the deprecated API. Hence the question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can try to add `SKStoreReviewController.RequestReview(Window.WindowScene)` in the FinishedLaunching method of your xxx.ios->AppDelegate.cs; start the project to see if it is correct.

If the above method goes wrong, using DependencyService is the right way to go.

Here is the interface code:

```
 public interface MyInterface
{
     void RequestReview();
}
```

Here is the implementation method of the interface in ios:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyInterfaceImpl))]
namespace App19.iOS
{
    public class MyInterfaceImpl : MyInterface
    {
        public void RequestReview()
        {
           var myv = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(14, 0);
            if (myv)
            {
                UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow();
            SKStoreReviewController.RequestReview(window.WindowScene);
            }
            else 
            {
                SKStoreReviewController.RequestReview();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it in the OnStart method inside APP.xaml.cs:

```
 protected override void OnStart()
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            DependencyService.Get<IReviewService>().RequestReview();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wanted an answer in xamarin.ios , not in swift

Comment: I edited my code and I successfully tested.

Answer (score 0):

I might have a solution:

```cs
using StoreKit;
using UIKit;

public void RequestReview(){
    var scene = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene;

    if (scene is null)
    {
        //handle the scene being null here
        return;
    }

    SKStoreReviewController.RequestReview(scene);
}
```

I've found multiple ways of getting the current scene and they both worked when I tested them:

```cs
var scene = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene;

var alsoScene = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow()?.WindowScene;
```

You can read more about the difference between the two in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21698751/4317797)

The complete solution where you check the iOS version in order to call the right thing might look like this

```cs
using StoreKit;
using UIKit;

public void RequestReview()
{
    var isIos14OrAbove = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(14, 0);
    if (isIos14OrAbove)
    {
        var scene = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene;

        if (scene is null)
        {
            //handle the scene being null here
            return;
        }

        SKStoreReviewController.RequestReview(scene);
    }
    else
    {
        SKStoreReviewController.RequestReview();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this function will fail if the scene is empty.

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT Would the `UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow()?.WindowScene` work better in that case?

Comment: The reason for the empty is that the project loads xxx.ios first and then runs the Forms file. So I call the method after FinishedLaunching executes. In this way, you can avoid the problem of null values that will not take effect.

Comment: The main thing is to avoid the occurrence of null values, and there cannot be a situation where the null value will not take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, it seems pretty obvious that you wouldn't call the `RequestReview` method before the app launches.. I'm guessing the most sensible usage of the `RequestReview` method would be after `OnStartup` or later, after the user has been using the app for a while. No reason to call it before the app launches.

Comment: After FinishedLaunching method.